# How to insert 4 rows after each row in a dataframe so each new row is +1 hour, +2 hours, +3 hours, +4 hours from original dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset similar to this example, with one column containing various date and time data for several events. There are other columns and rowws to the dataset that are not important here.

df =

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 2015-01-10 00:00:00 | 45 |
| 2017-12-19 10:00:00 | 67 |
| 2020-09-02 21:00:00 | 87 |

I am trying to add 4 rows of data after every existing row, so each new row adds 1 hour after the original data frame. The goal is to have something like this:

df_new =

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 2015-01-10 00:00:00 | 45 |
| 2015-01-10 01:00:00 |  |
| 2015-01-10 02:00:00 |  |
| 2015-01-10 03:00:00 |  |
| 2015-01-10 04:00:00 |  |
| 2017-12-19 04:00:00 | 67 |
| 2017-12-19 05:00:00 |  |
| 2017-12-19 06:00:00 |  |
| 2017-12-19 07:00:00 |  |
| 2017-12-19 08:00:00 |  |
| 2020-09-02 21:00:00 | 87 |
| 2020-09-02 22:00:00 |  |
| 2020-09-02 23:00:00 |  |
| 2020-09-02 00:00:00 |  |
| 2020-09-03 01:00:00 |  |

The contents of the B column in the new rows does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using a `cross_join`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df |>
  cross_join(y = data.frame(add = 0:4)) |>
  mutate(A = A + hours(add)) |>
  select(-add)
#                      A  B
# 1  2015-01-10 00:00:00 45
# 2  2015-01-10 01:00:00 45
# 3  2015-01-10 02:00:00 45
# 4  2015-01-10 03:00:00 45
# 5  2015-01-10 04:00:00 45
# 6  2017-12-19 10:00:00 67
# 7  2017-12-19 11:00:00 67
# 8  2017-12-19 12:00:00 67
# 9  2017-12-19 13:00:00 67
# ...
```

Using this sample data:

```
df = read.table(text = 'A   B
"2015-01-10 00:00:00"   45
"2017-12-19 10:00:00"   67
"2020-09-02 21:00:00"   87', header =T) |>
  mutate(A = ymd_hms(A))
```

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate the rows, then add the hours directly via addition and a `difftime` object:

```
df <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), each=5),]
df$A <- df$A + as.difftime(0:4, units="hours")

##                      A  B
##1   2015-01-10 00:00:00 45
##1.1 2015-01-10 01:00:00 45
##1.2 2015-01-10 02:00:00 45
##1.3 2015-01-10 03:00:00 45
##1.4 2015-01-10 04:00:00 45
##2   2017-12-19 10:00:00 67
##2.1 2017-12-19 11:00:00 67
##2.2 2017-12-19 12:00:00 67
##2.3 2017-12-19 13:00:00 67
##2.4 2017-12-19 14:00:00 67
##3   2020-09-02 21:00:00 87
##3.1 2020-09-02 22:00:00 87
##3.2 2020-09-02 23:00:00 87
##3.3 2020-09-03 00:00:00 87
##3.4 2020-09-03 01:00:00 87
```

Using [@Gregor's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77311613/496803) `df` example.